# Display COUNT() total at the Correct Row of Record

Tags: mysql, sql

## 1. Problem Statement

I am having a difficultly to display the total of `COUNT()` at the correct row of record.

How do I display the `COUNT()` to the correct respective service which is

## 2. Background

I want to display the output of showing the total of the project in charge by staff based on the `stage_id` and breakdown into `project_name`.

#### What I have attemped / tried

```sql
SELECT
    B.employee_name,
    B.project_name,
    A.total 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT( * ) AS total,
        services.NAME AS project_name,
        services.id AS service_id,
        users.id AS member_id,
        users.NAME AS member_name 
    FROM
        users
        LEFT JOIN projects ON users.id = projects.leader_id
        LEFT JOIN services ON projects.service_id = services.id 
    WHERE
        ( projects.service_id IN ( 1, 5 ) AND projects.stage_id < 6 ) 
        OR ( projects.service_id IN ( 2, 3, 4, 7 ) AND projects.stage_id < 7 ) 
    GROUP BY
        member_name,
        service_id 
    ) AS A
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        users.id AS user_id,
        users.NAME AS employee_name,
        services.NAME AS project_name,
        services.id AS service_id 
    FROM
        users,
    services 
    ) AS B ON A.service_id = B.user_id RIGHT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT users.id AS user_id, users.NAME AS user_name, services.NAME AS project_name, services.id AS service_id FROM users, services ) AS B ON A.service_id = B.user_id
```

I used this query to generate the output below

```
+-------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|   id  |   project_name    |   employee_name  |       total       |
+-------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|   1   |   Projects A      |   Employee A     |         2         |
|   2   |   Projects B      |   Employee A     |         2         |
|   3   |   Projects A      |   Employee B     |         3         |
|   4   |   Projects B      |   Employee B     |         3         |
|   5   |   Projects A      |   Employee C     |         1         |
|   6   |   Projects B      |   Employee C     |         1         |
|   7   |   Projects A      |   Employee D     |         2         |
|   8   |   Projects B      |   Employee D     |         2         |
+-------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

The total of count assigns into the wrong row of record.

## 3. SQL Fiddle

This is the example of the output I have created on SQL Fiddle.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08eff4/1/0

## 4. Expected Output

I am expecting the total of count can be assigned to the correct row of record.

#### Output Expectation

```
+-------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|   id  |   project_name    |   employee_name  |       total       | (COUNT (*) AS total) 
+-------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|   1   |   Projects A      |   Employee A     |         2         |
|   2   |   Projects B      |   Employee A     |        NULL       |
|   3   |   Projects A      |   Employee B     |         3         |
|   4   |   Projects B      |   Employee B     |        NULL       |
|   5   |   Projects A      |   Employee C     |         1         |
|   6   |   Projects B      |   Employee C     |        NULL       |
|   7   |   Projects A      |   Employee D     |         2         |
|   8   |   Projects B      |   Employee D     |        NULL       |
+-------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

I have running out of idea to achieve the expected outcome.
Hence, I would like to seek for help from the experts in this forum.

Comment: There is a lot of data and code to take in, can you simplify this into a smaller input and expected result? see [Minimum, Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Learn to use proper `GROUP BY`.  That `GROUP BY` is not even valid.

Comment: @Eric, sorry I don't understand. How come the query can be executed if the `GROUP BY` is not valid?

Comment: Probably run on old MySQL.  Newer MySQL and any other dbms will error out.

Answer (score 0):

**P/S: The field name might be different from the above because I write the query in a different schema**

I managed to find my answer after keep on trying.

```sql
SELECT
    A.NAME,
    B.NAME,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT( * ) 
    FROM
        projects
        LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = projects.leader_id 
    WHERE
        (
            projects.service_id IN ( 1, 5 ) 
            AND projects.stage_id < 6 
            AND users.id = A.id 
            AND projects.service_id = B.id 
        ) 
        OR (
            projects.service_id IN ( 2, 3, 4, 7 ) 
            AND projects.stage_id < 7 
            AND users.id = A.id 
            AND projects.service_id = B.id 
        ) 
    ) 
FROM
    users AS A
    CROSS JOIN services AS B
```

This is the query that output my expected result as below.

```
+-------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|   id  |   project_name    |   employee_name  |       total       | (COUNT (*) AS total) 
+-------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|   1   |   Projects A      |   Employee A     |         2         |
|   2   |   Projects B      |   Employee A     |        NULL       |
|   3   |   Projects A      |   Employee B     |         3         |
|   4   |   Projects B      |   Employee B     |        NULL       |
|   5   |   Projects A      |   Employee C     |         1         |
|   6   |   Projects B      |   Employee C     |        NULL       |
|   7   |   Projects A      |   Employee D     |         2         |
|   8   |   Projects B      |   Employee D     |        NULL       |
+-------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```